# GWT PopupPanel not showing animated Image correctly

Tags: java, gwt

I have a method in which i use gwt PopupPanel to display an image while screen loads and server workloads.

```
final static PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel(false, true);
```

The method i use is :

```
public static void sBanner() {

        popup.setWidget(new Image("Images//Progress.gif"));
        popup.setGlassEnabled(true);
        popup.center();
    }
```

What i dont manage to do it is to show the image when the method its called.

In local, runs fine; but when i deploy the code to Google App Engine, I get an icon like Google App Engine isnt finding the referenced file.

I have also tried to upload the image to Google Drive and use the sharing url as the url to use, but so far i havent been successful.

Anyone can enlight me?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  com.google.gwt.resources.client.ImageResource to provide images.

progress.gif should be in the same folder of Resources class (relative path can also be used-change @source value)

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
                @Source("progress.gif")
                ImageResource getPreloader();
            }





 Resources resources = GWT.create(Resources.class);
 popup.setWidget(new Image(resources.getPreloader()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response :-). I will implement it and see how it goes.